# Why am I getting Resources$NotFoundException when updating a TextView?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am writing a simple stopwatch application for android which will just keep the counter updating each second when pressed start, and pause it with the same button. In my main.xml layout I have a TextView and a Button, and nothing else.
Here's what I've written so far.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button btnToggle;
    private TextView tvStopwatch;
    public Handler updateStopwatch;

    private enum Status {
        WORKING,
        STOPPED
    }

    private Status stopwatchStatus;

    private void toggleStatus() {
        if (stopwatchStatus == Status.WORKING) {
            stopwatchStatus = Status.STOPPED;
            Stopwatch.getStopwatch().dispose();
            btnToggle.setText("Start");
        }else{
            stopwatchStatus = Status.WORKING;
            Stopwatch.getStopwatch().start();
            btnToggle.setText("Stop");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnToggle:
                toggleStatus();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void initView() {
        btnToggle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnToggle);
        tvStopwatch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStopwatch);

        updateStopwatch = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                tvStopwatch.setText(msg.what);
            }
        };

        Stopwatch.getStopwatch().setHandler(updateStopwatch);
        btnToggle.setOnClickListener(this);

        stopwatchStatus = Status.STOPPED;
    }



    public static class Stopwatch {

        private int timestamp;

        private boolean working;

        private Handler updateStopwatch;

        private Stopwatch() {

        }

        private static Stopwatch stopwatch;

        public static Stopwatch getStopwatch() {

            if (stopwatch == null) {
                stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            }
            return stopwatch;
        }

        public void setHandler(Handler updateStopwatch){
            this.updateStopwatch = updateStopwatch;
        }

        public void start() {

            if (!working) {

                working = true;

                Thread tick = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (working) {
                            try {
                                sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                timestamp++;
                                updateStopwatch.sendEmptyMessage(timestamp);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                tick.start();
            }
        }

        public void dispose() {
            working = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The point is, I want my Stopwatch work in it's separate thread, and to have a handler in my main UI thread which will keep updating the TextView, but when I debug my app, it keeps throwing an exception on this line

> tvStopwatch.setText(msg.what);

I am quite new to Handlers, so I guess I'm just missing something fundamental.
Here is also the log for the exception

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1057)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4186)
            at unisoftdevelopment.com.stopwatch.MainActivity$1.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:61)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help to find out the problem, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common mistake to make: `setText()` has an overload that takes an integer (which must be a string resource ID, e.g. R.string.my_string).

When you receive the message:

```
tvStopwatch.setText(msg.what);
```

It's attempting to resolve `msg.what` as a string resource, and crashing when it can't be found. You should instead cast the timestamp to a string, and use that instead:

```
tvStopwatch.setText(String.valueOf(msg.what));
```

Comment: omg)) yes, that was the problem, thank you very much) I was so concerned about the handlers ana threads that started to miss this kind of errors)

Comment: yet another question if you don't mind. it works properly, but when i press pause button on the 4th second for example, it still updates the textview to 5, i guess because the message for the handler is already in the queue, and then stops updating, how can i solve this problem?

Comment: After you set `working` to false, you only check it's value *before* sleeping. You should check it before *and* after the sleep (e.g. `if (!working) updateStopwatch.sendEmptyMessage(timestamp);`)